# Lidando com diferenças de JSON por causa de versões anteriores

Tags: json, web-service, mobile

Qual a melhor forma de lidar com o seguinte problema:

Tenho uma aplicação mobile iPhone e Android que enviam e recebem dados para um Webservice utilizando JSON. Minha aplicação precisa funcionar offline, com usuários podendo ficar semanas sem internet, e quando conseguirem conexão, o server recebe os dados e sincroniza.

No entanto, se houver uma mudança no Webservice nesse meio tempo, o JSON esperado pode mudar (exigência do cliente). Minha solução foi fazer uma camada de tratamento no Webservice que recebe pelo JSON a versão do App e converte os dados para o formato que o mesmo espera. 
O problema é que cada versão que haja uma mudança dessas exige que seja atualizado a camada de tratamento para cada uma das versões anteriores.

Gostaria de saber se existe um método melhor para tratar esse caso ou se já estou utilizando o melhor método.

Grato.

**EDIT:**

Sendo mais específico na camada de tratamento, eu estou tratando da seguinte forma:

1. AJAX recebe o JSON do App via POST, faz uma validação simples e passa-o
   para a classe AppDecoderGeral;
2. AppDecoderGeral verifica a versão e instancia a classe responsável pela respectiva versão do app (ex: AppDecoderAndroid70);
3. Classe AppDecoderAndroid70 instancia os models de acordo com suas
   regras;
4. Models são tratados pelos Controllers e DAOs, etc;

Meu problema está no passo 3, pois pensei em utilizar interfaces, no entanto, uma versão anterior pode não instanciar models que em versões mais recentes sejam obrigatórios (por exemplo quando uma nova funcionalidade é implementada).

Por enquanto estou seguindo tratando caso a caso, atualizando cada AppDecoder para lidar com novas funcionalidades, mas vejo que assim essas classes irão crescer indefinidamente.

Existe alguma forma melhor de tratar esse caso?

Answer (score 0):

Você já trabalho com versionamento certo? Então você já tem a solução na mão.

O que eu recomendo é indicar e usar um padrão quando for feita alterações na API, pode usar como base o Versionamento Semântico.

> Dado um número de versão MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH, incremente a:
>
> versão Maior(MAJOR): quando fizer mudanças incompatíveis na API,
>   versão Menor(MINOR): quando adicionar funcionalidades mantendo
>   compatibilidade, e versão de Correção(PATCH): quando corrigir falhas
>   mantendo compatibilidade. Rótulos adicionais para
>   pré-lançamento(pre-release) e metadados de construção(build) estão
>   disponíveis como extensão ao formato MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH.
>
> _
>
> Fontes: http://semver.org/lang/pt-BR/

Dessa forma você consegue trabalhar melhor e padroniza em caso de incompatibilidade, forçando o usuário atualizar a aplicação quando online. É **importante** que o usuário seja notificado no momento de uma nova versão e em caso de incompatibilidade explicar o motivo da atualização.

A sua solução funciona, mas, em meu ponto de vista não é eficiente, exige manutenção de ambos os lados de qualquer forma. E quanto mais cresce mais tratamentos você deverá fazer.

Espero ter sido claro quanto a ineficiência.

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno Diego, quanto ao versionamento estou tratando dessa forma no App, o que você sugeriu seria versionar a API também?

Comment: Editei minha pergunta para explicar melhor como estou fazendo a camada de tratamento. Criei essa pergunta justamente por causa dessa ineficiência que você comentou, mas ainda não achei uma solução melhor :)